# How to force pip uninstall in case of missing files

Tags: python, pip

I need to remove a corrupted old version of `setuptools` package from pip

unfortunately `pip uninstall setuptools`

doesn't work because cannot find some entries and returns me:

```
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file ...
```

errors

For the install procedure you can use `--ignore-installed` to continue the operation anyway for uninstalling procedure this flag seems not recognized.

What command should use to achieve the package deletion?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it manually by removing the directory and egg file. Look for site-packages directory and there should be something like setuptools.egg-info, delete (or move that) and then run the following with whatever version/location you are using:

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools

Answer (score 0):

Possible work-around: pip install --upgrade --I setuptools

Comment: this doesn't work. I already tried in this way and remains corrupted  setuptools

Comment: Now , I would suggest you to go brutal and issue `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/setuptools`